# Xcode Build Input File Cannot Be Found

Tags: swift, xcode

I decided to move my controller to a folder inside of the controller folder for better organization. After doing so, I am getting a `"Build input file cannot be found '/Users/.../Xcode/Development/.../.../Controller/ProfileController.swift'`

I looked for an answer to this thinking this has happened a lot but the only thing turned up was missing info.plist files which I believe this is different. I moved my file to `'/Users/.../Xcode/Development/.../.../Controller/Dashboard/Profile/ProfileController.swift'` which caused this issue.

Any idea how to resolve this? I'm assuming you can nest folders and that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like your Xcode project is referencing a file with an absolute path instead of relative path.

Answer (score 2):

Check on "build Phases" -> "Compile Sources" if the file is listed and maybe greyed-out or duplicated. Remove all those entries from the list, remove the file from the project tree (without trashing it) and re-drop it into the project.
Check again the file in the "Compile Sources". Now there should be once. Build.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it resolved itself but after restarting my Mac, I created another TestController inside of the new folder I wanted to reference, assigned that controller to the storyboard and finally I removed the TestController and placed my ProfileController back into the storyboard it started working.

Just thought I would post my solution for others in case it is helpful.